# Electron JavaScript Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Tags: javascript, electron

Hey I'm new to developing in Electron and I have no idea why I keep getting an error.

the app is declared in the first couple of lines

```
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {

if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
  app.quit()
}
})

app.on('activate', function () {

if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
  })
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sorry the error im getting is in the title.

Comment: Where is the app declared? Seems like you are missing the line.

Comment: This might help you - https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/issues/30

Comment: i added the app declaration

Comment: I checked that link and it says to not use the atom terminal and just use the vanilla one, im using the vanilla terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what the mistake I was making was, I added this line in my index.html file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">  </script>
```

That causes the error.